# Count the number of digits and letters inside a list?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Say that list(x) = ["12/12/12", "Jul-23-2017"]

I want to count the number of letters (which in this case is 0) and the number of digits (which in this case is 6).

I tried calling `x[i].isalpha()` and `x[i].isnumeric()` while iterating through a for loop and an error was thrown stating

> "TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str"

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about:

```
def analyze(s):
    return [sum(n) for n in zip(*((c.isdigit(), c.isalpha()) for c in s))]

strings = ["12/12", "12/12/12", "Jul-23-2017"]

for string in strings:
    print(analyze(string), string)
```

**OUTPUT**

```
[4, 0] 12/12
[6, 0] 12/12/12
[6, 3] Jul-23-2017
```

> I set the first sum to equal a variable called "digits" and the second
>   sum to a variable called "letters"

```
digits, letters = analyze("Jul-23-2017")
```

Answer (score 5):

Your error indicates that you either did `for i in x` (which makes no sense) or `for i in s` (where `s` is an element of `x`, a string). What you meant to do was `for i in range(len(s))`. Even better would be `c.isalpha() for c in s`.

Comment: `range(len(s))` is a python code smell.  There is almost always a better way to do it ... as you show in this case (less simple cases often involve `enumerate`)

Comment: Mmm, `sum(c.isalpha() for c in s)` works beautifully.

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ `map(str.isalpha, string)`.

Comment: Yes, and then the sum, since it seems that's what OP wants. :)

Comment: @AlexHall I think this makes sense. I was trying to iterate through every index in the list x. So in your example, s would be the items in list x?

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you want?

```
x = ["12/12/12", "Jul-23-2017"]
sum(1 for word in x for c in word if c.isdigit())  # 12
sum(1 for word in x for c in word if c.isalpha())  # 3
```

Comment: `sum(c.isalpha()/isdigit() for c in word)` is a lot more concise.

Comment: @Bit I will actually be loading my data from a column, row by row from a Pandas Dataframe. So for example, my first three rows are as such ["12/12", "12/12/12", "Jul-23-2017"]. I set the first sum to equal a variable called "digits" and the second sum to a variable called "letters". Using the list comprehension you sent me, "digits" = 6 and "letters" = 14 for all three rows.

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this:

```
def count(L):
  dgt=0
  letters=0
  for s in L:
    for c in s:
      if str(c).isdigit():
        dgt+=1
      elif str(c).isalpha():
        letters+=1
  return (dgt, letters)


>>> count(["12/12/12", "Jul-23-2017"])
#returns (12,3) - There are 12 digits and 3 chars ('J', 'u', 'l')
```

If you want to print a tuple for each word in the list you can do:

```
def count(L):
  for word in L:
    yield (sum(s.isdigit() for s in word), sum(s.isalpha() for s in word))

for t in count(L):
 print t
#outputs:
(6, 0)
(6, 3)
```

Comment: I think OP wants a string wise count.

Comment: @user3079275 I actually just need a count of the amount of letters, and the amount of digits, so a string wise count. I will be loading row by row from a pandas data frame.